# Incompatible generic type in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a complex generic type implementation in Java but I could not complete it. I am getting error on `AddItemEvent` class. The return type in the `getHandler` does not match with it's parent class requires.

`AddItemEventHandler` is actually a `BaseEventHandler<BaseEvent<AddItemCommand, AddItemPayload>, AddItemCommand, AddItemPayload>` but I get an error on that line.

```java
public abstract class BasePayload {
}

public class AddItemPayload extends BasePayload {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public AddItemPayload(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class BaseCommand<T extends BasePayload> {
    String command;
    T payload;

    public BaseCommand(String command, T payload) {
        this.command = command;
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}

public class AddItemCommand extends BaseCommand<AddItemPayload> {
    public AddItemCommand(AddItemPayload payload) {
        super("AddItem", payload);
    }
}


public abstract class BaseEventHandler<E extends BaseEvent<C, P>, C extends BaseCommand<P>, P extends BasePayload> {
    abstract public void onTry(E event, ArrayList<BaseEvent<?, ?>> actualEvents);
    abstract public void onCommit(String uuid, E event);
}

public class AddItemEventHandler extends BaseEventHandler<AddItemEvent, AddItemCommand, AddItemPayload> {
    @Override
    public void onTry(AddItemEvent event, ArrayList<BaseEvent<?, ?>> actualEvents) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCommit(String uuid, AddItemEvent event) {
    }
}


public abstract class BaseEvent<C extends BaseCommand<P>, P extends BasePayload> {
    abstract protected BaseEventHandler<BaseEvent<C, P>, C, P> getHandler();
}

public class AddItemEvent extends BaseEvent<AddItemCommand, AddItemPayload> {
    @Override
    protected BaseEventHandler<BaseEvent<AddItemCommand, AddItemPayload>, AddItemCommand, AddItemPayload> getHandler() {
        return new AddItemEventHandler(); // I have an error on this line
        /*
        Incompatible types. Found: 'org.example.handlers.AddItemEventHandler',
        required: 'org.example.handlers.BaseEventHandler<org.example.events.BaseEvent<org.example.commands.AddItemCommand,org.example.payload.AddItemPayload>,
        org.example.commands.AddItemCommand,org.example.payload.AddItemPayload>'
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign a variable of type `List<AddItemEvent>` to a reference of type `List<BaseEvent<AddItemCommand, AddItemPayload>>`. That's because the latter allows more - it allows not just `AddItemEvent` instances, but any instance that extends `BaseEvent<AddItemCommand, AddItemPayload>`.

Your compiler error has the same cause. The handler would allow more than only `AddItemEvent` instances.

One solution can be to add an extra generic type to `BaseEvent` for the event itself:

```java
public abstract class BaseEvent<E extends BaseEvent<E, C, P>, C extends BaseCommand<P>, P extends BasePayload> {
    abstract protected BaseEventHandler<E, C, P> getHandler();
}
```

That has to be propagated to some of the other types:

```java
public abstract class BaseEventHandler<E extends BaseEvent<E, C, P>, C extends BaseCommand<P>, P extends BasePayload> {
    // additional ? in BaseEvent
    abstract public void onTry(E event, ArrayList<BaseEvent<?, ?, ?>> actualEvents);
    abstract public void onCommit(String uuid, E event);
}

public class AddItemEventHandler extends BaseEventHandler<AddItemEvent, AddItemCommand, AddItemPayload> {
    @Override
    // additional ? in BaseEvent
    public void onTry(AddItemEvent event, ArrayList<BaseEvent<?, ?, ?>> actualEvents) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCommit(String uuid, AddItemEvent event) {
    }
}

// additional generic type: AddItemEvent
public class AddItemEvent extends BaseEvent<AddItemEvent, AddItemCommand, AddItemPayload> {
    @Override
    // replace BaseEvent<AddItemCommand, AddItemPayload> with AddItemEvent
    protected BaseEventHandler<AddItemEvent, AddItemCommand, AddItemPayload> getHandler() {
        return new AddItemEventHandler(); // no more error
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the AddItemEventHandler exnteds too. After that it is working.
`public class AddItemEventHandler extends BaseEventHandler<BaseEvent<AddItemCommand, AddItemPayload>, AddItemCommand, AddItemPayload>`